# Select specific data from input form in yii

Tags: php, sql, yii

I have a problem selecting a field in an input form.
I need to insert a new manager permission when adding a new manager and this doesn't work.

```
if(isset($_POST['Manager']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['Manager'];
            if($model->save()){
                $sql = "insert into authassignment (itemname, userid, bizrule, data) values (:itemname, :userid, :bizrule, :data)";
                $parameters = array(":itemname"=>'manager' , ':userid' => $_POST['username'], ':bizrule' => null,':data' => null);
                Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql)->execute($parameters);
                $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->username));}
        }
```

The problem is at the parameters array ar `':userid'` placeholder.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller, check post data using

```
print_r($_POST);
```

your username should be

```
$_POST['Manager']['username']
```